# Infopath: How to set a default value based on view

Tags: infopath, infopath-rules

I have created a `Leave Request` site within my organization.  I have a list which hosts the 3 following `leave types: Annual, Special and Sickness`.  I have a choice field in the list named "Leave Type" which has a dropdown of all 3 types.

I have 3 different `New Request` views and I am linking to these from promoted links on my homepage.  I want the `Leave Type` to change for each view so that it is correct for each list entry.

Rather than a `Form Load` rule, I need some kind of `View Load` rule.

Can anyone advise?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: Did you help my answer? Mark it please.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just change your choice field to a static field based on the view? So if your user browses to the "Leave request: Annual Leave" view of your list, have the only option for leave as Annual. Same for your Sickness and Special.

If you wanted them to be able to change it, then the drop down list is the way to go, but I'm not sure you can set a rule to set default based on the view.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand you correctly.

You are using InfoPath forms, so you are able to do this with Inputs Parameters to the forms. [Here described with examples](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/infopath/2007/02/26/passing-data-into-a-form-input-parameters/). After correct set you will be able to create 3 different links to the form with wanted selected value. After loading value from the input parameter, you can set the value of DropDown in InfoPath by this code:

```
#setNodeValue("/my:myFields/my:Form/my:LeaveType, "Annual");
#setNodeValue(XPath, ValueString);
public void setNodeValue(string path, string value)
    {
                XPathNavigator root, infopathNode;
                root = this.MainDataSource.CreateNavigator();
                infopathNode = null;
                infopathNode = root.SelectSingleNode(path, this.NamespaceManager);
                infopathNode.SetValue(value);
    }
```

Links will look like:

- https://sp.com/sites/LeaveRequest/NewForm.xsn?RequestType=Annual
- https://sp.com/sites/LeaveRequest/NewForm.xsn?RequestType=Special
- https://sp.com/sites/LeaveRequest/NewForm.xsn?RequestType=Sickness